# Curl static compilation problem (X509_NAME) on Windows with BoringSSL 1.1.0

Tags: libcurl, nmake, cl, boringssl

I have a recent problem when I try to compile Curl static lib on windows with BoringSSL. The above commands where working fine 6 months ago, but with latest versions of Curl and BoringSSL I came into an issue in the nmake command.

What I'm doing:

```
call buildconf.bat

cd "winbuild"

set RTLIBCFG=static
set _CL_=-MTd -Ob0 -Od -Zi -FS

call nmake /NOLOGO /X - /F MakeFile.vc VC=16 mode=static MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=yes WITH_PREFIX="C:/cpplibs/Curl" WITH_SSL=static SSL_PATH="C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL" ENABLE_SSPI=yes ENABLE_IPV6=yes ENABLE_IDN=yes ENABLE_WINSSL=no
```

What I face with in console output:

```
Generating prerequisite files
* C:\cpplibs\Sources\Curl\latest\Makefile
* C:\cpplibs\Sources\Curl\latest\src\tool_hugehelp.c
configuration name: libcurl-vc16-x64-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi

cl /O2 /DNDEBUG /MT /DCURL_STATICLIB /I. /I ../lib /I../include /nologo /W4 /EHsc /DWIN32 /FD /c /DBUILDING_LIBCURL /DUSE_OPENSSL /I"C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL"  /DUSE_WIN32_IDN /DWANT_IDN_PROTOTYPES  /DUSE_IPV6  /DUSE_WINDOWS_SSPI /Fo"..\builds\libcurl-vc16-x64-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi-obj-lib/altsvc.obj"  ..\lib\altsvc.c
altsvc.c

... 100+ successfull calls

cl /O2 /DNDEBUG /MT /DCURL_STATICLIB /I. /I ../lib /I../include /nologo /W4 /EHsc /DWIN32 /FD /c /DBUILDING_LIBCURL /DUSE_OPENSSL /I"C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL"  /DUSE_WIN32_IDN /DWANT_IDN_PROTOTYPES  /DUSE_IPV6  /DUSE_WINDOWS_SSPI /Fo"..\builds\libcurl-vc16-x64-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi-obj-lib/vtls/openssl.obj"  ..\lib\vtls\openssl.c
openssl.c

C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/base.h(362): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509.h(154): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509.h(154): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '('
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509.h(154): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509.h(154): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509.h(154): error C2091: function returns function
...
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509_vfy.h(508): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'X509_STORE_get_lookup_crls'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509_vfy.h(508): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509_vfy.h(508): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'

C:/cpplibs/BoringSSL/openssl/x509_vfy.h(508): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

So I've investigated, and all the errors at the indicated lines seems to have in common the X509_NAME typedef usage, but the definition is correct in openssl/base.h:

```
typedef struct X509_name_st X509_NAME;
```

And in openssl/x509.h:

```
struct X509_name_st {
    STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY) * entries;
    int modified;  // true if 'bytes' needs to be built
    BUF_MEM *bytes;
    //  unsigned long hash; Keep the hash around for lookups
    unsigned char *canon_enc;
    int canon_enclen;
} /* X509_NAME */;
```

Furthermore the file ..\lib\vtls\openssl.c in Curl lib includes <openssl/x509v3.h> that includes <openssl/x509.h> that includes <openssl/base.h> ... So everything should be OK, but it's not.

Is there something missing in my commands ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No I wasn't :-(